Retrieve content from a document library and display it as HTML on a SharePoint page
My requirement is to retrieve a document from a document library on a site and extract its content to display it as HTML, rather than displaying the document directly using SharePoint as a CMS.
Do I need to create a custom web part for this? Could you provide any examples in C# of how to achieve this, or is there a simpler way.
